# Command to retrieve all informations from a website

Tags: unix

is there a unix command to retrieve all informations possible from a website?

I mean info like: IP, IP geo location, (sub-)domains, alternative domain names, name server, and all other informations I'm thinking about.

I know about `whois`, but is there anything else? 
Something that gives more informations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any command that can do all of that at once but a simple pipeline should work too.

1. `ping www.website.com` for IP
2. `curl ipinfo.io/ip-adress` for geo-location
3. `nslookup -query=soa www.website.com` for original DNS

Alternatively you can use the command `dig` to find the subdomains via the DNS:

4. `dig domain.com` the output in the authority section are the DNS servers which are used
5. `dig @dns.server domain.com AFXR` to retrieve the subdomains of domain.com